# In the ORCA tool how to bring the "custom action of set up proj" before the "InstallValidate" action?

Tags: windows-7, windows-services, installation, windows-installer, orca

I am upgrading the version of my app from 1.1.1 to 1.1.2 (say).
I have created a set up project for the application using VS2005 & have added a custom action which would programatically end a service running in the previous version(1.1.1) before installing newer version 1.1.2.

But "InstallValidate" happens before custom action.

Hence need to use ORCA to change the sequence i.e I want the custom action to execute before the InstallValidate executes.

> Can anyone kindly help me with the
>   detailed steps to bring
>   "InstallValidate" after custom
>   actions.

I am new to the MSI database manipulations.

Thnks In advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Orca go to InstallExecuteSequence and find your custom action. Modify its **Sequence** field so it has a sequence lower than InstallValidate.

Comment: I am facing problem in locating the Custom action in the InstallExecuteSequence table. Beacuse I don't find any entry in the table corresponding to my custom action.   Can u Plz guide me with this.

Comment: Where did you add your custom action in the setup project?

Comment: I have added my custom action "Primary output of XYZ" under the "Install" option in the set up proj.